# embed or object tag to play YouTube videos without iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I need to autoplay the YouTube video on click of a link. Below is the code I have tried. The video isn't automatically played.

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
var videoSrc;

function CustomVideoClick(url) 
{
    videoSrc = String(url).replace("watch?v=", "embed/");

    $("#customVideo").attr("data", videoSrc + "?                        
     autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0");
    
}
</script>
<div >
    <object id="customVideo" data="" >    
      
    </object>
</div>
```

I don't want to use an `iframe`. Is there any way to autopplay and allowfullscreen the YouTube video using either an `embed` or `object` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because most browsers restrict `autoplaying` videos. See [AutoPlay Policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

Some browsers may allow autoplaying if you add `&mute=1`

Comment: Thanks. Also is it possible to allow full screen using embed/object tag?

Comment: You can just set height and width of the embed/object tag to 100%